# Controlling motors same as WS2812b works (Neopixels)

Tags: shift-register, addressing

Im a beginner and trying to achieve a weird scenario (Could be). There is around 30 tiny DC motors for each of those I need to make it individually controllable. Same as WS2812b led works. How can I make it possible? I heard WS2812b is a kind of shift register inside of it and it can control the next LED connect to it. So is it possible for custom devices rather than LED(in my case motor).

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Are we going to design the electronic circuits needed for you ? Nope.

Comment: If you dont mind can you give a  little hint on how to make it... Sorry am a very beginner

Comment: Hmm, the only little hint I can give is: start much, much simpler and work your way up in electronics. Or just re-build a design someone has already made and is proven to work. There are no "little hints" that can make you from a beginner into someone who can design their own bus-controlled motor control system. It is just too complicated. Most people take **many years** to learn how to do that.

Comment: small motors need 100x more current than those LEDs and bidirectional current. http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/tutorial/h-bridge/index.html

Comment: Can you do it? Yes. Hell you could use addressable led drivers with mosfet and (ab)use them for motors. The concern is power. How are you going to run power to these motors?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use a small (6 or 8 pin) microcontroller to control the motors. You will have to program it, but it won't be much code most likely, perhaps a page or two. You will also need a driver for the motor most likely, as the pins from a micro can usually only supply some tens of mA. Easy for unidirectional, a bit more complex for bidirectional brushed DC motor drive or steppers.